# Pass whole Model through ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass a whole Model through my jQuery's ajax call?
For know I can only get it working if i set one variable at the time.

As the code shows I pass the *iVideo_ID* through the ajax call. The Video object has a lot of other fields. So instead of writing all the attributes, can i pass the whole existing object (Video Model)?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
    url: "/Video/UpdateComment", // Controller/View
    data: { //Passing data
        iVideo_ID: '@(Model.Video.iVideo_ID)'
    }
});
```

I have tried with this but it just return a Model that is null:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
    url: "/Video/NyMetode", // Controller/View
    data: '@(Model)'
});
```

So how can i pass the whole model? Is it possible?

EDIT:
My View Model I try to pass:

```
public class CommentViewModel
{
   public List<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
   public List<Tasks> Tasks { get; set; }
   public Videos Video { get; set; }
   public List<VideoTaskScores> VideoTaskScores { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your `model` and also equivalent `cshtml` code? Are you binding this in form element?

Comment: Use `data: $('form').serialize()` to serialize all the name/value pairs of your form control (note that you current code is attempting to pass the original model back to the controller which would be a bit pointless)

Comment: I haven't used form control in this case. I'm trying to pass a viewModel which consists some lists. But i don't see the way to pass the whole view model to the my post method.

Comment: var model = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'); then return inside the ajax--------------------------- data: modelName : model ,

Comment: Then what are you trying to do? What in is the point of passing a model to a view and then posting it back to the controller unchanged?

Comment: The thing i do now is just passing a few parameters to the controller and then update a value in my database, and then do another database call to pass all the values back to the view. Everytime I do that I wait for the database. Instead i would like to store all my changes in a new List locally. At the end the user can press save changes and all different changes will be changed in the database at the same time. Therefore if i could pass my existing model back and some new attributes, and then do some locally changes i would have the new list at the end to do the database call

Comment: @AsifRaza it gives me a System.InvalidOperationException. Perhaps it's because I try to pass a view model and not just a single attribute?

Comment: If you are trying to pass back changes a user may make, then the solution is more complicated; this is a solution I once came up with, which uses Kendo templating and also allows additions to the list: https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/asp-net-mvc-and-client-side-lists-with-kendo/

Comment: @BrianMains I will look at your solution. Thanks man.

Comment: You can use Json.stringify(model) but before implement this you you should get your Lists of model class with their last states by using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

actually ya you can do that

just change around a bit for more simplification I.e

```
<script>
var jsonData= @html.raw(json.encode(Model));
```

then in ajax data

```
data: modelName : jsonData,
```

just make sure in your actionresult the param name is also modelName  ie

```
public ActionResult ActionName(model modelName)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It give an System.InvalidOperationException error. The problem is: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: is it a list ?? your model

Comment: Yes it is. Or it's actually a ViewModel so there's a couple of lists. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: can you please post your viewmodel

Comment: you make sue the parameter in action result is also the same view model object

Comment: I have updated the my post with the view model. Yes it is the same view model object

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your cshmtl page :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetModel() {      
            return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        }
</script>
```

And this how you can send WHOLE model:

```
var ModelData = GetModel();
 $.ajax(
        {
                        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                        url: "/Video/UpdateComment", // Controller/View
                        data: { ModelName: GetModel(); }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It give an System.InvalidOperationException error. The problem is: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: I have added the View Model i try to pass. The @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); only works if i pass a single variable into it, like: Model.Video.iVideo_ID

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the model properties within a form and then serialize the form and pass it your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/ActionName",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#MyFormName').serialize()
            })
                .done(function (response) {
        alert(response.Message);                        

                    }
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert(Something went wrong);  
                });
```

And in the action you can directly access your model as

```
public ActionResult ActionName(MyModel modelObj)
    {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Json.stringify(model)` but before implement this you you should get your Lists of model class with their last states by using jQuery.

Can you try this

```
// you can get your model data from view by jQuery
// your model has list objects so you should get these from view and add these into model
var model = {...}; // your object corresponds model object

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
    url: "/Video/UpdateComment", // Controller/Action
    data: Json.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function (res) {
    // after done insert your code here
});;
```